# how to fix "forced cast" with xyz "only unwraps and bridges" in xCode and Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors

I see this error in the Analyze output for an app we are taking over:

```
/Users/bonnie/dev/elappa/Classes/FLAppGateway.swift:27:40: Forced cast from 'Error?' to 'NSError' only unwraps and bridges; did you mean to use '!' with 'as'?
```

The associated code block is like:

```
func fetchCountryCodes(_ completion: GetCountryCodesCompletion?)
{
    let parameters = parametersToFetchCountryCodes()

    serverManager?.postRequest(toURN: kGetCountryCallingCodes,
                               parameters: parameters,
                               domain: kUBPublicContentDomain,
                               success: { (object) in
                                self.handleGetCountryCodesSuccess(forObject: object as AnyObject?, completion: completion)
    }) { (object, error) in
        completion?(.failure(error as! NSError))
    }
}
```

I am new to Swift. I read about Optionals and understand this is some issue with doing a forced class cast (using "as!") but not sure what. Any ideas?

elsewhere I see this code:

```
typealias GetCountryCodesCompletion = (Result<CountryCodes?, NSError>) -> ()

protocol AppGateway
{
func fetchCountryCodes(_ completion: GetCountryCodesCompletion?)
func marketingContents(completion: ((Result<[MarketingContent], NSError>) -> ())?)
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this Analyze/compiler warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happens because you are force casting using `as!` from a swift style `Error` to objective-c style `NSError` and this cannot be done.

So if you really need `NSError`, simple create one from your `Error` object by filling in the follow code

```
let objcError = NSError(domain: "somedomain", code: 123, userInfo: [:])
```

And then

```
completion?(.failure(objcError))
```

Comment: But what does the error message actually mean? In my case I have a Data? and I'm trying to convert it to CFData using as!. Of course it's convertible — they are bridged. Why does this error occur? Thanks.